# I can't add JLabel to the collection. Why HashSet size is still 0?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I can't add JLabel to the collection. listOfFiles == 3 diffrent files. System.out.println(set.size()) still return 0.

```
public HashSet<JLabel> startCheckedFiles(){
        HashSet <JLabel> set = new HashSet<>();
        File folder = new File("utwory\\");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(1==1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                            set.add(new JLabel(listOfFiles[i].getName())); //listOfFiles == 3 diffrent files
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        final Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        System.out.println(set.size()); // return 0
        return set;
    }
```

Why HashSet size is still 0?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reason that `System.out.println(set.size())` could be printing zero:

1. The child thread hasn't actually started by that point in time.
2. The child thread has started, but the (infinite!) loop cannot find anything to add to the set; e.g. `listOfFiles` is empty.

But there are other problems with your code:

1. Why are you repeatedly labels for the same set of files to the set ... in an infinite loop?
2. I don't see the point of using a child thread here, especially since you don't want to return from `startCheckedFiles()` until the set has been populated.
3. The code as written is not thread-safe.  The child thread is updating the `HashSet` and the parent thread is looking at the set's size ... *without doing any synchronization*.   And (presumably) the caller for `startCheckedFiles()` will be doing the same.  That is a recipe for "unpredictable things happening".